# How to assign a random location (x,y) to a variable

Tags: python, geometry, position, pi

I'm trying to generate `1000-10000` points with random position inside a circle ( which is drawn inside a square) with `radius of 1`, and by using the formula `x^2 + y^2 = 1` to decide whether which one is inside the circle. I got the idea but I'm pretty new to python so I don't exactly know how to execute them

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page. Your question is either too broad or off topic: this isn't a tutorial or discussion forum.

Comment: In addition to the methods described in the question above, you can also just use rejection sampling: generate a point and see if it is in the circle, then generate a new one if needed. Repeat until you get a point in the circle.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a random integer by using this example:

```
import random

random.randint(0,10) # this returns and integer between 0 and 10
```

Now that you know how to generate random integers, you can apply to your logic.

For more details, check the [randint documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint).